# Lost with Partial Diff Eq's (Heat Equation)

Tags: integration, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

> Let $u$ be a smooth solution to:
>
> $\partial_t u - \Delta u = 0$, $(t, x) \in (0, \infty)$ x $\mathbb{R}^3$
>
> such that $u$ and its derivatives are rapidly decreasing as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$ (say, bounded by $(1 + |x|)^{-4}$ as $|x| \rightarrow \infty$; this is more than necessary). Prove that:
>
> $\int_{\mathbb{R}^3} u(t, x)$ $dx$ is constant in $t$.

I'm honestly completely lost on how to start this question. I know it has to do with the heat equation... I think I have to plug in the fundamental solution into the integral, and then take the derivative with respect to $t$ to show that it's constant. Am I on the right track? Any guidance would be greatly helpful, because I'm very lost with this subject. Thank you.

Comment: Prove what? You showed just an integral.

Comment: Oops, my bad, thought I typed in the last bit. Fixed!

Comment: Great job. Another question: does only $u$ when $|x| \to \infty$ is bounded or also $y$ and $z$ are similar to that as well?

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: Why you defined you equation only for $x,t$ if it is in $R^3$

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar I think that $x = (x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb R^3$, so there is no $y$ or $z$ in our notation here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(t) = \int_{\mathbb R^3} u(t,x) \, dx$. Then
$$
f'(t) = \int_{\mathbb R^3} \partial_t u \, dx = \int_{\mathbb R^3} \Delta u \, dx.
$$
Now notice that $\Delta u = \nabla \cdot \nabla u$ (in other words, the Laplacian is the divergence of the gradient) and use the divergence theorem to show that the integral on the right is zero.

Comment: Ah, I see.. I think I was way overthinking it. Thank you.